# script to find out missing indexes in one database when compared with other identical database in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

i have two databases say test1 and test2,both are identical i.e both have same tables with same names.but test1 has some indexes on the tables which are missing in test2 database.how to write script to find out those missing indexes in test2 database when compared with test1 database in sql server 2012.i tried below script but it showing all the indexes.but i want only missing indexes in test2 database when compared with test1 database.

```
select *
  from
       (select s1.name           as SchemaName
              ,t1.name           as TableName
              ,c1.name           as ColumnName
              ,i1.name           as IndexName
              ,i1.index_id
              from test1.sys.schemas s1
          join test1.sys.tables t1
            on t1.schema_id = s1.schema_id
          join test1.sys.columns c1
            on t1.object_id = c1.object_id
          join test1.sys.types ty1
            on ty1.system_type_id = c1.system_type_id
           and ty1.user_type_id = c1.user_type_id
          join test1.sys.index_columns ic1
            on ic1.object_id = c1.object_id
           and ic1.column_id = c1.column_id
          join test1.sys.indexes i1
            on i1.object_id = ic1.object_id
           and i1.index_id = ic1.index_id) r1
  full outer join
       (select s1.name           as SchemaName
              ,t1.name           as TableName
              ,c1.name           as ColumnName
              ,i1.name           as IndexName
              ,i1.index_id
          from test2.sys.schemas s1
          join test2.sys.tables t1
            on t1.schema_id = s1.schema_id
          join test2.sys.columns c1
            on t1.object_id = c1.object_id
          join test2.sys.types ty1
            on ty1.system_type_id = c1.system_type_id
           and ty1.user_type_id = c1.user_type_id
          join test2.sys.index_columns ic1
            on ic1.object_id = c1.object_id
           and ic1.column_id = c1.column_id
          join test2.sys.indexes i1
            on i1.object_id = ic1.object_id
           and i1.index_id = ic1.index_id) r2 
    on r1.SchemaName = r2.SchemaName
   and r1.TableName = r2.TableName
   and r1.ColumnName = r2.ColumnName
   and r1.IndexName = r2.IndexName
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `left outer join` and add at the end `where r2.IndexName is null`